# Valid Azure Storage URI returning not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to retrieve all image files from a virtual directory in my Azure storage account. The path of the folder (container URI) is correct but is returning

> StorageException: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.

Pasting the URI in the browser produces

> `BlobNotFound`
>   The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:622f4500-a01e-0022-7dd0-7d9428000000 Time:2019-10-08T12:02:29.6389180Z

The URI, which is public, works fine; you can see this video by pasting the URI in your browser or clicking the Engine Video link below.

[Engine Video](https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck/publicfiles/images/robson/Robson_CatR475_CrankcaseTeardownVideo.mp4)

My code grabs the container, whose URI is https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck/publicfiles/images/robson

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetBlobFileListAsync(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer, string customer)
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        //code fails on the line below
        var segments = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);           
        blobContinuationToken = segments.ContinuationToken;
        files.AddRange(segments.Results.Select(x => GetFileNameFromBlobUri(x.Uri, customer)));
    } while (blobContinuationToken != null);
    return files;
}
```

The code is failing on the var segments = await blobContainer…. code line
and it is not the container that is causing the error (IMO) as you can see the container comes back with a valid URI

[image: Container Uri]

and the virtual folder contains files

[image: Storage Explorer View]

I would love to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri...you are the expert here, any thoughts on this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer lies in the fact that I am trying to list blobs WITHIN a virtual folder path
So in the OP, I was trying to list the blobs using the FULL path to the folder containing the blobs. You cannot do it that way. You must use one of the overloads of ListBlobsSegmentedAsync on the MAIN CONTAINER. Thanks to juunas for getting me to realize I wasn't starting at the main container. I realized their must be other overload methods to accomplish what I was seeking to do

The code below works well

```
public async Task<List<EvaluationImage>> GetImagesFromVirtualFolder(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer, string customer)
    {
        var images = new List<EvaluationImage>();
        BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
        do
        {
           //this is the overload to use, you pass in the full virtual path from the main container to where the files are (prefix), use a
          //useflatbloblisting (true value in 2nd parameter), BlobListingDetail, I chose 100 as the max number of blobs (parameter 4) 
          //then the token and the last two parameters can be null       
            var results = await blobContainer.
                ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("publicfiles/images/" + customer,true,BlobListingDetails.All, 100, blobContinuationToken,null,null);
            // Get the value of the continuation token returned by the listing call.
            blobContinuationToken = results.ContinuationToken;

            foreach (var item in results.Results)
            {
                var filename = GetFileNameFromBlobUri(item.Uri, customer);
                var img = new EvaluationImage
                {
                    ImageUrl = item.Uri.ToString(),
                    ImageCaption = GetCaptionFromFilename(filename),
                    IsPosterImage = filename.Contains("poster")
                };

                images.Add(img);
            }
        } while (blobContinuationToken != null);

        return images;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck/publicfiles/images/robson` is not a container URI.

`https://batlgroupimages.blob.core.windows.net/enerteck` is a container URI.
`publicfiles/images/robson/image.png` could be a blob's name in that container.

I'm thinking you may have included some of the virtual folder path in the container URI and maybe that is messing up something?

Comment: @juunas...yes, /publicfiles/images/robson is a virtual folder path. So are you suggesting the container I pass in is just the main container? If so, how do I iterate on just the virtual file path I want instead of all the blobs in the container? and putting the container URI you have in your post, ending in enerteck, also produces a resource not found error.

Comment: I think you might be able to do a prefix filter, like get all files that start with the virtual folder path. But the fact that you still can't list files is a bit odd. Could you add some more code to your question where you show how you initialize the paths etc?

Comment: @juunas...you're correct, when using the main container, the code doesn't fail, but it only returns two blobs, the two subfolders under the main container, privatefiles and publicfiles. There has to be a way to iterate thru files in a virtual folder path

Comment: @juunas...so you were right about using the main container. I fooled around with the other overloads, which is how to go. If you add to your answer to use the first overload with the 7 parameters, Ill mark your answer as the answer. you need the prefix, BlobListingDetails and the FlatBlobListing value to get the files in a virtual folder path.